# SO says I made a change that I didn't make

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

I edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2315476/revisions), but I only made one change: adding a dollar sign before the line `func_name();`. But it says that I also added some text, "*that consumes a lot of resources*".

I'm certain that I didn't add that text; in fact, I'm not even so sure it's correct!

Is it possible that the original author added that text, and it somehow got lumped in with my edit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

About the only thing that would make sense is that the author originally included that text in his post when you hit the edit button and made your change. As you were making your edit, the author removed that text from his post within 5 minutes of posting it preventing it from becoming a new revision. When you submitted your change you then unknowingly put that sentence back into the post, and the system credits you with the addition.

Comment: Yea, this 5 min grace/ghost period triggered quite a number of confusion.

Comment: Sounds pretty likely.

Comment: Yep, I've seen exactly this same scenario, and it's caused confusion. In one particular case recently I made a tag edit to a question prior to commenting on it. The OP then edited the question, including a fairly fundamental change that resulted in my comment being wrong. I then had to defend myself from another commenter who thought I was responsible for both an incorrect comment and a major edit to the question. It all ended up okay, but it was a bit awkward for a time.

Answer (score 4):

Just a wild guess, maybe the 5 Minute Grace Period creates a race condition here? (Authors are able to change their posts within 5? minutes without the edit showing up as edit/revision, but I would guess it's still tracked)