# Edit record disappeared

Tags: support, edits, edit-summary

I just edited the answer by hopeseekr to this question.

[How do I save data in an application scope in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713311/how-do-i-save-data-in-an-application-scope-in-php)

I removed a short sentence at the start of the answer.

There is no record on the answer or when you hit edit of my change.  I'm not worried about this from an ego point of view, but I am worried that something is going wrong with the site code.

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/bug-report-so-says-i-made-a-change-that-i-didnt-make) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make).

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3713311/revisions

If you made multiple revisions within 5 minutes, bear in mind they will be treated as one single revision.

This is due to the 5 minute editing grace period.

Comment: Responding to Jeff, I also edited the question, which is what you point to, but its the change I made to the answer that doesnt show.