# Revision history is attributing edits to me that I didn't make

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My suggested edit includes changes that I did not make](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116725/my-suggested-edit-includes-changes-that-i-did-not-make)

The revision history groups temporally-close question edits together, which is fine.

But in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13709792/revisions) my edit was *only* the "it's" -> "its" (and let's keep arguments over whether or not my edit was valid for another day); the OP made all the others.

The revision history has incorrectly attributed some of his following edits to me.

Answer (score 3):

No, your edit was based on a version of the post that subsequently changed. Your change was substantial enough to still be recorded anyway.

Because the post had changed in the meantime, your edit *reverted* some of the edits the OP had made in the meantime.

In other words, the OP, since you opened the editing window, changed `It can be useful if the return type is unspecified` to `It can be useful when the return type of a function or member function is unspecified`, and added a comma after `boost.bind`. You started editing a version without these changes, and when saved, reverted those changes. The revision history shows the difference based on that.

Comment: Yet the revision history shows those changes being added, not taken away. Is this an oddity caused by the OP's first changes (that my edit hypothetically accidentally rolled back, as you identify) being wrapped up in the grace period and thus not recognised in the edit history? This results in a completely non-representative revision history page, IMO. It shows me taking actions that I did not take, and if that's because the prior actions by someone else are simply not displayed then isn't that going beyond a mere shrug-it-off edit race condition?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The edits the OP made were merged in the edit history (they were made in the grace period).